How to properly setup tensorflow with GPU acceleration on NixOS
In advance, I have just started using NixOS, so please forgive me if I make seemingly basic mistakes.
I have looked up what feels like the entirety of the Internet in the search of the solution to my problem.
Here is my shell.nix so far:
with import <nixos> {};

mkShell {
 name = "tensorflow-cuda-shell";
 buildInputs = with python311Packages; [
 cudatoolkit
 cudaPackages.cudnn
 tensorflowWithCuda
];
 shellHook = ''
   export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=${pkgs.stdenv.cc.cc.lib}/lib:${pkgs.cudaPackages.cudatoolkit}/lib:${pkgs.cudaPackages.cudnn}/lib:${pkgs.cudaPackages.cudatoolkit.
lib}/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
   alias pip="PIP_PREFIX='$(pwd)/_build/pip_packages' TMPDIR='$HOME' \pip"
   export PYTHONPATH="$(pwd)/_build/pip_packages/lib/python3.9/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH"
   export PATH="$(pwd)/_build/pip_packages/bin:$PATH"
   unset SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH
 '';
}

This is an amalgamation of the wiki page on tensorflow (which seems outdated), responses on forums, and scraping GitHub for custom configs. With this shell script it currently takes ages to compile everything from source. It has been at least an hour, but it still compiles binaries. Is there any way to speed this up?
Any idea of how to run tensorflow with GPU acceleration is deeply appreciated. Seems like this issue was not brought up for a very long time and all of the resources are outdated.

Jesus, I've figured it out.
I referenced this post on NixOS discourse. It is just a nix-shell command, but it worked for me. Now I wanted to instead create shell.nix file.
Here's what you need to do:

Open ~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix and write:

{ cudaSupport = true; allowUnfree = true;  }


shell.nix

{ pkgs ? import <nixpkgs> {}, config ? {} }:
let
 pythonPackages = pkgs.python3.withPackages (ps: [ ps.tensorflow ]);
in
pkgs.mkShell {
 name = "tf";
 buildInputs = [
   (pythonPackages)
 ];
 shellHook = ''
   export PYTHONPATH="${pythonPackages}:${PYTHONPATH:-}"
 '';
}

(thank you ChatGPT!)

Now run nix-shell
python
Run:

import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')


???
Profit!

